# Dynamic UITableView header (not section header) auto layout problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, header, autolayout

I need to add tableViewHeader to UITableView, that contains two labels and everything needs to be dynamically resized with auto layout. So, I created a header view in XIB, measured it with `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` and set the view to tableViewHeader. The result looks like this:

[image: result]

As you can see, the label with author's name ("Brian Mancini") has extra space above and below the text. How can I get rid of it?

**-UPDATE-**

Here is the demo project: [link](http://dsh.re/6a490) and here is the screen shot of *Interface Builder* constraints of the view:

[image: IB constraints]

Comment: Could you share your constraints in your .xib file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lately I fixed the same issue with table header view auto layout in my project. You'd better provide more information about your current IB configurations so that I can try to help more efficiently, but below let me try translating my solution to the context of your project to see if it helps:

1. Put the 2 labels in a container (UIView)
2. Configure necessary constraints to achieve the layout you wish ( Simply do the same as what you've done to set up the constraints between the labels to the top most view before)
3. Configure the necessary margins between the container and the top most view

Doing this way, table header view height calculation is no longer necessary. Let auto layout does the job for you!

Here is how it should look like (The yellow box is the added container view, everything else stays the same as you wish)

[image]

Also note that you should call `layoutIfNeeded` after assign the custom view to the table header view, otherwise it doesn't know where it is to adjust ;)

[image]

Please find the fixed version [HERE](https://github.com/dobaduc/SO-32356226)

Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry for the delay – I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the source later! Marked the answer.